# Javascript Regex for amount field(not allow digits other then zero after decimal point)

Tags: javascript

I am doing amount validation and i want to write a regular expression in the below format,

1) It should not allow digits but zero(0) can allow after decimal point (i.e, not allow numbers like 23.33, 12.24 but allow 13.00)

2) Decimal point not mandatory for the amount field

I tried using the following code but its taking digits after decimal point,

```
 /^(?!0)\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet?

Comment: i tried like this, /^(?!0)\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/ but its taking digits

Answer (score 1):

Forget about regex, all you need is check if :

```js
function is_valid(num) {
  return num == (num|0)
}

console.log(is_valid(24.33))
console.log(is_valid(23.00))
console.log(is_valid(12))
console.log(is_valid('12.67'))
console.log(is_valid('12.00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A better method for ECMA Script 2015 or later: `Number.isInteger(num)` **(IE not supported)** (I have to admit
that it may be slower, though.)

Besides `num | 0` which floors a number, sometimes I will also use `~~num`. There are many other methods like `Math.floor(num)`, though. See **[here](http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/58-fastest-alternative-to-math-floor-in-javascript)** for more information.

But if you really like a regular expression (not suggested): `/^\s*[+-]?\d+(\.0*)?\s*$/`

- Remove `\s*` to disallow spaces.
- Change `[+-]` to `-` to disallow positive signs.
- Change `0*` to `0{0,2}` or `0{1,2}` to allow only up to 2 d.p.

Visit **[here](https://regex101.com)** to design and check your own regular expression.

[Document for `Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)

---

Actually you should use `<input type="number">` instead. (IE 10+)